# Get value from iterated text field using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a one text field that has been loop for many times and it has value that came from database and i want to get the value of each text field that has been loop for many times the first text field works but when i click but the other text field it doesn't seems to work here is the

```
$("#order").click(function()
{   
    var IDno_textfield = $("#IDno_textfield").val();
    var name_textfield = $("#name_textfield").val();
    
    alert("ID no: " + IDno_textfield + " " + " Name: " + name_textfield);
});
```

this is for the javascript code this my code for getting the values in iterated one text field

```
            <?php
              $c = 0;   
                if($result->num_rows > 0) 
                {                                   
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                    {                                       
            ?>          <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src = "data:image/jpeg; base64 , <?php echo base64_encode($row['product_image']); ?>"height = "250" width = "330">
                            <br>
                                    <div id = "order">
                                            Order now
                                    </div>
                            </td>                       
                            <td>
                                No.
                                    <input type = "text" value = "<?php echo $row['product_IDno']; ?>"
                                    id = "IDno_textfield">
                                    <br>
                                Name: 
                                    <input type = "text" value = "<?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>"
                                    id = "name_textfield">
                                <br>
                                Price:
                                        <input type = "text" value = "<?php echo $row['product_price']; ?>"id = "production_textfield">
                                <p>
                                    Description: <?php echo $row['product_description']; ?>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>   
            <?php
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "No Menu Found";
                }
            ?>
```

And this is for the php code that fetch the data to textfield and iterate the text field for many times

[image]

this is the result it only works once at the first textfield but not to other text field . i will be glad if you help me thanks

Comment: `id`s should be unique within the document.

Comment: No two IDs can be the same. Change the ids to names or classes as they allow non-unique values.

Comment: i should change the id to class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for different id's of elements you can do this:

```
          <?php 
          $c = 0;   
            if($result->num_rows > 0) 
            {                                   
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                {                                       
         ?>     
     <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="data:image/jpeg; base64 , <?php echo base64_encode($row['product_image']); ?>"height="250" width="330">
                    <br>
                            <div id="order-<?php echo $row['product_IDno']; ?>" class="order">
                                    Order now
                            </div>
                    </td>                       
                    <td>
                        No.
                            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['product_IDno']; ?>" id="IDno_textfield-<?php echo $row['product_IDno']; ?>">
                            <br>
                        Name: 
                            <input type="text" value = "<?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>" id="name_textfield-<?php echo $row['product_IDno']; ?>">
                        <br>
                        Price:
                                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['product_price']; ?>" id="production_textfield-<?php echo $row['product_IDno']; ?>">
                        <p>
                            Description: <?php echo $row['product_description']; ?>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>   
    <?php
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No Menu Found";
        }
    ?>
```

and javascript

```
 $(".order").on('click', function()
 {   
    var productID = $(this).prop('id').replace('order-', '');

    var IDno_textfield = $("#IDno_textfield-" + productID).val();
    var name_textfield = $("#name_textfield-" + productID).val();

    alert("ID no: " + IDno_textfield + " " + " Name: " + name_textfield);
});
```

Each element on the page should have unique identifier "id". To the id's of elements in the loop including the button "Order" just add the identifier "id" of product itself and so every "id" will be different. Each button "Order" does it belong to the same class equal for all the buttons "Order" but always different for id. Subsequently, on onclick to button of that class takes the value of the property "id" and removing the generic part for all, in your case "order-" so it remains the unique part (id) with which you can find the elements concatenating the generic part with id thus obtained.

Comment: can you explain how did you do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#order").click(function() {
var IDno_textfield = $(this).parent('tr').find("#IDno_textfield").val();
var name_textfield = $(this).parent('tr').find("#name_textfield").val();
alert("ID no: " + IDno_textfield + " " + " Name: " + name_textfield);
});
```

Comment: it prompts a undefined value for the both variable.

Comment: You should use class name instead of ID (IDno_textfield, name_textfield)

Comment: it is still the same .

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`<?php
              $c = 0;   $count = 0;
                if($result->num_rows > 0) 
                {

                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                    { $count++;

            ?>          <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src = "data:image/jpeg; base64 , <?php echo base64_encode($row['product_image']); ?>"height = "250" width = "330">
                            <br>
                                    <div id = "order" data-attr = "<?php echo $count; ?>">
                                            Order now
                                    </div>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                No.
                                    <input type = "text" value = "<?php echo $row['product_IDno']; ?>"
                                    id = "IDno_textfield_<?php echo $count; ?>">
                                    <br>
                                Name: 
                                    <input type = "text" value = "<?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>"
                                    id = "name_textfield_<?php echo $count; ?>">
                                <br>
                                Price:
                                        <input type = "text" value = "<?php echo $row['product_price']; ?>"id = "production_textfield_<?php echo $count; ?>">
                                <p>
                                    Description: <?php echo $row['product_description']; ?>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

            <?php
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "No Menu Found";
                }
            ?>`

and the click event will change to.......

```
$("#order").click(function()
{   
    var id = $(this).attr('data-attr')
    var IDno_textfield = $("#IDno_textfield_"+id).val();
    var name_textfield = $("#name_textfield_"+id).val();

    alert("ID no: " + IDno_textfield + " " + " Name: " + name_textfield);
});
```

Comment: it's still the same thank you and i appreciate your help

Comment: you mean the bind() method ?